# HTML <img src> cannot find my picture under Android

Tags: c#, android, html, image, xamarin.forms

I'm having a Xamarin Forms project and I want to generate an HTML file. For this reason, I save my needed pictures in Download/MyName folder on the device(Android) together with my HTML. But HTML `<img src="mypic.jpg">` cannot find my picture.
Please note that I'm using the device memory.

Comment: Have you tried using a `file://` style reference in your `src`?

Comment: Can you please show your HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with file:// and it doesn't work. Here is the part of my html, where I'm testing the picture
<img src="file://tempProfilePicture.jpg" style="border:5px dotted #8B603D;border-radius:50%;margin:15px;padding:0;width:200px">

https://pastebin.com/FgB5eXr4

Comment: Here is the folder https://www.dropbox.com/s/v41jgrmp7o1ov3w/Screenshot_20180517-005948.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you presenting this `html` through a webview?

Comment: I don't present it at all. I'm opening separately afterwards.